# Why is part of viewmodel Null?

Tags: c#, asp.net-core, model-view-controller

I have a viewmodel which I'm using to give and remove admin permissions.

It consists in the following

```
    namespace PenedaVes.ViewModels
{
    public class RootViewModel
    {
        public List<UserBox> UserBoxesList;
        public string TestAtributte { get; set; }
    }

    public class UserBox
    {
        public string UserId { get; set; }
        public string Username { get; set; }
        public bool IsChecked { get; set; }
    }
}
```

The Test atribute is just being used in debugging to check if the whole viewmodel comes in null or is it just the list.
Then I have a controller, called Panel controller which has a get and a post method:

```
        public async Task<IActionResult> Index()
        {
            List<ApplicationUser> users = await _userManager.Users.ToListAsync();

            List<UserBox> userBoxes = new List<UserBox>();
            
            foreach(ApplicationUser user in users)
            {
                if (await _userManager.IsInRoleAsync(user, "Root")) continue;
                UserBox ub = new UserBox
                {
                    UserId = user.Id,
                    Username = user.UserName,
                    IsChecked = await _userManager.IsInRoleAsync(user, "Admin")
                };
                    
                userBoxes.Add(ub);
            }

            RootViewModel vm = new RootViewModel {UserBoxesList = userBoxes, tipo = "Hello"};
            
            return View(vm);
        }

        [HttpPost]
        public async Task<IActionResult> ChangePermissions(RootViewModel vm)
        {

           Console.WriteLine(vm.Test)
           Console.WriteLine(vm.UserBoxerList.Count)
        }
```

Finally the used view is the following:

```
@model RootViewModel

@{
    ViewData["Title"] = "Index";
    Layout = "~/Views/Shared/_Layout.cshtml";
}

<h1>Admin permissions pannel</h1>

<form asp-controller="Panel" asp-action="ChangePermissions" method="post">
    <table>
        <h3> User List</h3>
        @for (int i = 0; i < Model.UserBoxesList.Count; i++)
        {
            @if (i % 3 == 0)
            {
                @:<tr></tr>
            }
            <td>
                @Html.CheckBoxFor(model => model.UserBoxesList[i].IsChecked)
                <label> @Model.UserBoxesList[i].Username</label>
                @Html.HiddenFor(model => model.UserBoxesList[i].Username)
                @Html.HiddenFor(model => model.UserBoxesList[i].UserId)
            </td>
        }
    </table>
    
    <div class="form-group form-check">
        <label class="control-label">
            <input class="form-check-input" asp-for="@Model.TestAtributte" /> This is a test attribute
        </label>
    </div>
    
    <input type="submit" value="Change" class="btn btn-primary" />
</form>
```

Whenever I submit this form the TestAtribute always comes with the new value, however, the list comes as a null value and throws a NullReferenceException, which confuses me since it was not null when presented in the view.

Any help would be greatly appreciated.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

> Whenever I submit this form the TestAtribute always comes with the new value, however, the list comes as a null value and throws a NullReferenceException

That is because `UserBoxesList` in your model is a field instead of a property.

Modify your model like below:

```
public class RootViewModel
{
    public List<UserBox> UserBoxesList { get; set; }
    public string TestAtributte { get; set; }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

When you are posting through your ChangePermissions method, the RootViewModel view
you have passed as a parameter will have the UserBoxesList as null since your model class RootViewModel does not have the UserBoxesList initialised.

Try this:

```
public class RootViewModel
{
    public List<UserBox> UserBoxesList;
    public string TestAtributte { get; set; }

    public RootViewModel()
    {
       UserBoxesList = new List<UserBox>();
    }
}
```

This has worked for me in the past with collections and complex class structures within the model.